# In the C program, try to use strsep to instead the startok, but doesn't work

Tags: c

The following is the code that can run, and I want to change the `strtok(buf, delim)` to `strsep(&ptr, delim)` but it does not work. After the following code, I have the code I wrote; is my idea wrong?

```
FILE *f;
char buf[BUFSIZ], *p, *t;

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f) != NULL) {

    i = strlen(buf);
    if (buf[i-1] == '\n')
        buf[i-1] = '\0';
    for (i = 1, t = strtok(buf, delim);
             t != NULL && *t != '#';
             i++, t = strtok(NULL, delim)) {
        if (i == column)
            break;
    }
```

The code I wrote:

```
FILE *f;
char *p, *t;
const size_t BUFSIZE = 10000;
char *ptr=(char*)malloc(BUFSIZ);

while (fgets(ptr, BUFSIZ, f) != NULL) {

    i = strlen(ptr);
    int index=i-1;
    if (*(ptr +(index)) == '\n')
        *(ptr +(index))  = '\0';
    for (i = 1, t = strsep(&ptr, delim);
               t != NULL && *t != '#';
               i++, t = strsep(&ptr, delim)) {
        if (i == column) 
            break;
    }
```

The error:

```
==21288== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==21288==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==21288==    at 
==21288==    by  main 
==21288==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==21288==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==21288==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==21288==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
```

Comment: In the rewrite, since `ptr` initially holds the only pointer to the allocated memory, altering `ptr` via the `strsep()` call bodes ill — you can't free the memory, and the next `fgets()` will be operating on the wrong data, and ...  Make a copy of `ptr` and let `strsep()` work on that.  Use subscripts — the notation `if (*(ptr +(index)) == '\n')` etc is unreadable and ghastly.  Better, use `ptr[strcspn(ptr, "\n")] = '\0';` which works reliably even on empty strings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How to  make copy of ptr, like char *ptr2=ptr?